# Bitnami Wordpress phpmyadmin not able to connect to mysql

Tags: mysql, wordpress, bitnami

I am using the wordpress stack by bitnami in my local.

I had installed it a year back.

Now when i try to login into wp_admin i don't remember the username/password.

I am also not able to connect to phpmyadmin to look out the username/password set.

I am getting the following error

```
phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server rejected the connection. You should check the host, username and password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server.
```

Below is my config.inc.php's relevant portions of username/password settings of phpmyadmin

```
  /**
 * Authentication method (valid choices: config, http, signon or cookie)
 *
 * @global string $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type']
 */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';

/**
 * HTTP Basic Auth Realm name to display (only used with 'HTTP' auth_type)
 *
 * @global string $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_http_realm']
 */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_http_realm'] = '';

/**
 * MySQL user
 *
 * @global string $cfg['Servers'][$i]['user']
 */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';

/**
 * MySQL password (only needed with 'config' auth_type)
 *
 * @global string $cfg['Servers'][$i]['password']
 */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';

/**
 * whether to allow root login
 *
 * @global boolean $cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowRoot']
 */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowRoot'] = true;


$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
```

And below is my my.cnf of mysql

```
[mysqladmin]
user=root

[mysqld]
basedir=/Applications/wordpress-4.9.4-4/mysql
datadir="/Applications/wordpress-4.9.4-4/mysql/data"
port=3306
socket=/Applications/wordpress-4.9.4-4/mysql/tmp/mysql.sock
tmpdir=/Applications/wordpress-4.9.4-4/mysql/tmp
max_allowed_packet=32M
bind-address=127.0.0.1
skip-name-resolve=1

character-set-server=UTF8
collation-server=utf8_general_ci
[client]
port=3306
socket=/Applications/wordpress-4.9.4-4/mysql/tmp/mysql.sock

default-character-set=UTF8
[manager]
port=3306
socket=/Applications/wordpress-4.9.4-4/mysql/tmp/mysql.sock
pid-file=/Applications/wordpress-4.9.4-4/mysql/tmp/manager.pid
default-mysqld-path=/Applications/wordpress-4.9.4-4/mysql/bin/mysqld.bin
```

I can see the configuration in my phpmyadmin to connect to mysql is correct but still am not able to connect. May be i am missing something simple.

Best Regards,

Saurav

Comment: Do you have command line access to mysql and can you restart mysql?

Comment: Did not work...restarted mysql through manager application...not able to login through CLI also

Comment: Then you need to reset the root password.

Comment: i did the reset of root password and update the password in confic.inc.php of phpmyadmin app . It worked

Answer (score 0):

Just to answer how to resolve the generic problem if you are not able to login wp_admin area of Bitnami Wordpress stack. Also if the scenario gets complicated by forgetting the password of mysql.

1. First reset the root password using this link

   https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/resetting-permissions.html
2. Update the password in the config.inc.php, the config file of phpmyadmin
3. Then login into phpmyadmin and follow the steps to change the user password of wp_admin.

   https://www.fixrunner.com/cannot-login-wordpress-admin-area/